# How to pass parameters to a program running inside a batch file using java?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I am working on automating the process of database upgrade for a product.
The current practice is executing different executionables(e.x. CDXPatch.exe) which are found in several patches. Each one of the patch asks for database credentials.

While automating the process, I found out that I cannot execute CDXPatch.exe directly from processbuilder class. As it throws an unable to open CDXPatch.par file. So, my Java program began to write a batch file in which it would call the CDXPatch.exe and then started executing it using the process builder class.

During its execution by the running batch file, this (CDXPatch.exe) asks for password internally utilising java console methods and it also asks for things like "Press Enter" or "Type Y and Enter".

I tried following *two approaches* **:-**

**1)** I passed the password by writing to the outputStream connected to the batchfile's inputstream. 
"This approach gives me an unable to create a secure console error."

**2)** I wrote a VBScript, during the batch file's run it would execute after CDXPatch.exe and pass parameters to it.

"The VBScript passes the parameters to the CDXPatch.exe but only in the beginning. I don't know of a way in which the VBScript would wait for the CDXPatch.exe to prompt for an input and then provide it with an appropriate one."

Thanks for anything you can do to help me!

Comment: You have a java program that write a batch that write a vbs? I would fix the java program to launch correctly your "patch thing"

Comment: The java program runs the batch file( it calls the vb script stored on the disk).